Can I use pex brass fitting to connect to galvanized pipe?
I have a project where someone cut a galvanized pipe in half because they had a drip in the tee it’s connected to.
Can I use pex brass fitting with female barb to transfer the galvanized pipe to pex?

You will have to remove the cut pipe back to a threaded fitting. Plumbers in my area prefer to remove all the galvanized pipe. If that is not possible because of constraints, most do not like to connect with a dielectric union or a brass fitting. (Galvanized and brass should not be put together. Galvanic action will cause corrosion and eventual failure.)  The prevailing belief is that when connecting to galvanized pipe, using a brass fitting or the dielectric union is a "temporary" fix and should be followed with a plan to replace galvanized.
You can get galvanized to CPVC adapters in whatever size you need. ( both female and male are available. Use some Thread sealer on any threads. Then go from CPVC to pex with another adapter. This keeps the galvanized separate from other dissimilar metals.
